How to write this code so that it takes into account selected option in dropdown list?
image file - Price calculator
Hi. I am new to coding and started to write the code for my air conditioning price calculator. The code is currently looking like this:

var input1 = document.getElementById("inp1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("inp2");
var result = document.getElementById("coolculate");
function calculate() {
    var theProduct = parseInt(input1.value) * parseInt(input2.value) * (0.15);
    document.getElementById('invest_output_result').innerHTML = theProduct.toFixed(1);
};

result.onclick = calculate;

So what it is doing for example if user inputs "5" and "6" into length and width inputs it will multiply 5*6 and then multiply this result by 0.15 (which is the right amount of kilowatts in case if user has chosen "Metres"). But if user wants to choose the "Feets" then I need a different multiplication. I will need to multiply the sum not by 0.15 but by 0.014. At the moment this code using by default "Metres". But I have added the dropdown list which has an ID "m_or_f". And I need somehow maybe to assign ID to the two options that I have - "Metres" and "Feets"? Also I need to prompt the user to choose something in case if nothing is selected in the dropdown list.
So I started to write something like this but I know that this is wrong because "Metres" and "Feets" options dont have ID and I cannot assign ID to options, so it will not work. So what would be the correct final code after I have added the dropdown list with options? Thanks
if (Metres) {
 
  var theProduct = parseInt(input1.value) * parseInt(input2.value) * (0.15);
  document.getElementById('invest_output_result').innerHTML = theProduct.toFixed(1);

} else if (Feets) {

  var theProduct = parseInt(input1.value) * parseInt(input2.value) * (0.014);
  document.getElementById('invest_output_result').innerHTML = theProduct.toFixed(1);
} else {

  var theProduct = 0;
}


I somehow done what I wanted but at the moment the calculation happens on change of dropdown option selection (I have added onchange="calculate(this)" event to the dropdown list in HTML). But I want to do calculation only when I press "Coolculate" button which has an ID "coolculate".
Here is the GIF of how it works at the moment: https://viki.b-cdn.net/gif_xnVXGSpD.gif
At the moment my code is looking like this:
<script>
var input1 = document.getElementById("inp1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("inp2");
var e = document.getElementById("m_or_f");
var value = e.value;
var result = document.getElementById("coolculate");
function calculate(answer) {
    if(answer.value == 1) {
var theProduct = parseInt(input1.value) * parseInt(input2.value) * (0.15);
  document.getElementById('invest_output_result').innerHTML = theProduct.toFixed(1);
} else if (answer.value == 2) {

  var theProduct = parseInt(input1.value) * parseInt(input2.value) * (0.014);
  document.getElementById('invest_output_result').innerHTML = theProduct.toFixed(1);
} else {

  var theProduct = 0;
}
};

result.onclick = calculate;

</script>

